# Get the data even if it is null

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

How will I get the all the date even though there is no order between two dates?

Sample Table

```
OrderID  | Date      | CusID
33942    | 6-21-2014 | 6005
34059    | 6-20-2014 | 4003
53333    | 6-23-2014 | 6005
59234    | 6-23-2014 | 4003
```

How I could have this result?

```
CusID   | Date      | OrderID |
4003    | 6-20-2004 | 34059   | 
4003    | 6-21-2004 | null    | 
4003    | 6-22-2004 | null    | 
4003    | 6-23-2004 | 59234   | 
6005    | 6-20-2004 | null    | 
6005    | 6-21-2004 | 33942   | 
6005    | 6-22-2004 | null    | 
6005    | 6-23-2004 | 53333   |
```

This what I did so far.

I create a calendar table

```
CREATE TABLE #Calendar
(
    [CalendarDate] DATETIME
)

DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME
SET @EndDate = GETDATE()
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(Year, -1, @EndDate)


WHILE @StartDate <= @EndDate
      BEGIN
             INSERT INTO #Calendar
             (
                   CalendarDate
             )
             SELECT
                   @StartDate

             SET @StartDate = DATEADD(dd, 1, @StartDate)
      END
```

Then here is my query but does not give me the needed result

```
Select t.CusID, c.CalendarDate, t.OrderID 
From #Calendar c 
left outer join
#temp t
ON
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), c.CalendarDate, 112) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), t.Date, 112)
Where c.CalendarDate Between '6-20-2014' and '6-23-2014'
Order By t.Name
```

Comment: Added sql-server tag because syntax is clearly SQL Server.

Comment: Try using ISO standard dates:  YYYY-MM-DD instead of locale-specific date formats for the constants.

Answer (score 0):

You have a good start with the calendar table, but you also need a customer table, because your sample is looking for every possible combination of customer and calendar date. Once you build those, you will do a (rare) CROSS JOIN between the two before the join to your #temp table.

Also, for best results, just use the `Date` type, rather than `DateTime`, in the calendar table, and cast your `#temp.Date` column to a date, rather than converting to a string. This will be ***much*** faster.

Put it all together like this:

```
Select c.CalendarDate, t.OrderID t.CusID
From #Calendar c 
CROSS JOIN (select distinct CusID FROM #temp) cus
left outer join #temp t ON c.CalendarDate = cast(t.Date as date)
Where c.CalendarDate Between '2014-06-20' and '2014-06-23'
Order By t.Name
```

You may also want to duplicate that where clause in the derived table (subquery), to avoid listing unwanted customers.

Comment: Sorry but the version of my SQL Server don't have date datatype.